# cy.visit() doesn't load page from wrapped context object

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am gathering urls on website and then try to visit them. As I have to get attribute `href` using `then()` function my array `const imageRefs = new Array();` is empty outside of then. I wrap it to an object and give it an alias. The problem is that `cy.visit()` doesn't load any pages inside `cy.get('@imageRefs').then((imageRefs)...` and test fails.I tried to pass `baseUrl` as an argument together with `imageRefs` but it didn't help. Maybe anyone knows what can be done here?

```
    describe('crawler', () => {
      it('searchHighUsageAssets', () => {
        cy.visit('https://www.shutterstock.com/search/3d character');
        const imageRefs = new Array();
        cy.get('[data-automation="AssetGrids_GridItemContainer_div"]').each(
          ($element, $index, $collection) => {
        cy.get('[data-automation="AssetGrids_GridItemContainer_div"]')
                .eq($index)
                .children()
                .first()
                .invoke('attr', 'href')
                .then(($assetUrl) => {
                  imageRefs.push($assetUrl);
                  cy.wrap(imageRefs).as('imageRefs');
                });
        cy.get('@imageRefs').then((imageRefs) => {
        cy.visit($baseUrl + imageRefs[i]);
           
    }
     });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You should move the image loading part outside the `.each()` loop.

Cypress is going to get very confused if you start changing the page while it is in the middle of evaluating the links.

```js
cy.get('[data-automation="AssetGrids_GridItemContainer_div"]')
  .each(
    ...
  )
  .then(() => {                                
    cy.get('@imageRefs').then((imageRefs) => {
      ...
    })
  })
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to process gathered refs (@imageRefs) inside the loop

Comment: There is no reason to process the refs inside the loop.

Comment: This is how my scenario is composed. I gather all links iterating through children and then process them (visit). After that when I visited all links I open Next page  and use the same loop for images on the next page. How would you recommend change this architecture?

Comment: @Feldeisen, I tried to move image processing after the loop and visiting reference doesn't work